# Github desktop commit issues

Tags: github, github-desktop

Adding a separate folder in the repo and committing it is adding commit comments on all the folders. How do I only commit a folder without adding commit status/comments on other folders on my repository?

Comment: im not sure what you mean here. Empty folders cannot be committed using git.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is very unclear. What does "it is adding commit comments on all the folders" mean? Please read [ask].